# How I can get custom field's current value?

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, color-picker

I have "Color Filters for WooCommerce" plugin and "color" taxonomy.

Each taxonomy have one custom field - color picker.

I want to display on archive page current color picker value of each product's.

I can call

```
get_option( 'nm_taxonomy_colors' );
```

And I'll get all values from this field, but I need only current.

This plugin have [doc](https://www.elementous.com/documentation/color-filters-for-woocommerce/modifications-and-development/), but I don't know how I can use this filters

```
elm_cf_get_terms_args
elm_cf_color_style_attribute
```

Comment: Hi, I think the plugin only provides filtration and does not show individual product's colors. You should check all the meta_values for each product_id. You may find selected colors there. Try using `get_meta_values()`.

Answer (score 1):

The author of plugin help me with that. Thanks all.

```
global $post;
        $product_colors = get_the_terms( $post, 'product_color' );
        $saved_colors = get_option( 'nm_taxonomy_colors' );

        if(isset($product_colors) && is_array($product_colors)){
            foreach($product_colors as $color){
                $term_id = $color->term_id;

                $hex_code = $saved_colors[$term_id];

                echo $hex_code . '<br />';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this.

```
$saved_colors = get_option( 'nm_taxonomy_colors' );
//just use current term_id here.
$color = @$saved_colors[$current_term_id];
echo $color //anywhere you want on single product page.
```